# HTML Text Fields and Buttons appear bigger than specified

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I am implementing UI design in one of my own projects, and it looks like I have an issue with CSS, big time.

As far as I know, I have specified styles for Input types : text, buttons in the way CSS accepts:

```
body input[type=text]{
    border:1px solid #208278;
    height:24px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
body button{
    background-color: #279A8F;
    border:0px;
    color:white;
    height:24px;
}
body input[type=password]{
    border:1px solid #208278;
    height:24px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
body input[type=submit], input[type=button]{
    background-color: #279A8F;
    border:0px;
    color:white;
    height:24px;
}
```

On the login page, the fields appear to be of 24px in height, where as after I log in, I see all the fields are bigger, with height more than 24px. I have no clue.
One point is after logging in, the fields are present in a container which has some padding, and margins, but I don't see any reason how this would affect the fields. This issue has been driving me crazy nuts, can someone please provide some insight?

The container in which the form fields are placed are below:

```
#container{
    width:1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#leftbar{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    font-size:13px;
    background-color:#237971;
    color:white;
    padding:4px;
}
#rightbar{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color:#237971;
    color:white;
    padding:4px;
}
#middlebar{
    padding:5px;
    margin-left:3px;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
    width:660px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML Code of Log in page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="<?php echo base_url('layout/layout.css');?>" media="all">
    <title>
        My Page
    </title>

</head>
<body>
<div id=header>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Welcome
</div>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>


<?php echo form_open('login/verify'); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="email">E-Mail:</label></td>
        <td align="left"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?=set_value('email')?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right"><label for="password">Password:</label></td>
        <td align="left"><input type="password" name="password" id="password"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="left"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
 </form>
<br/>
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>signup/signup">Sign up</a> for a new account<br/>
</body>

</html>
```

HTML Code of member's area:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-1.9.1.js'); ?>"></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js'); ?>"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('js/jquery-ui/css/customjqueryui/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css');?>">



    </script>
    <link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="<?php echo base_url('layout/layout.css');?>">
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id=container>
    <div id=header>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Members area
    </div>


    <div id="leftbar">
        <div class=content><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/home/logout">Logout</a></div></div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
        <div id="middlebar">
            <?php echo validation_errors();?>
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('home/create/validate'); ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right"><label for="fullname">full Name:</label></td>
                    <td align="left"><input type="text" name="fullname"></td>
                </tr>


<tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="finish" value="Finish"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        <div id="rightbar"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

All the fields in the member's area appear bigger than 24px. :( Please help me!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example would be great! :) Without HTML we cannot proceed. :)

Comment: Is `body` really necessary in all of your input selectors?

Comment: Is it optional? I guess all the fields within the body tag share that property? Correct me if I am incorrect, please.

Comment: Use Chrome's developer tools or Firebug for Firefox to figure out where the extra size is coming from. Chances are pretty good it's just the element's padding.

Comment: Yes, body is optional and probably unnecessary in this case

Comment: Tried a quick jsfiddle mock-up http://jsfiddle.net/GCtDy/. Seems fine here. . .

Comment: @All, 
Thank you very much for your responses, I have debugged it using Firebug, and as per what it shows, the height of the input field is 20px, instead of 24. I tried making it 30 and it takes only 26, I wonder where the remaining is going. Inside the members area, the field correctly takes 24px. I have no clue again. Can someone throw some light into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the main fault,
I was not standardizing the login page with the statements below in my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```